# DataFrame replace multiple keys in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace, merge

Given 2 DataFrames :

DF1 (a Serie) :

```
Col_Name_1
[['A, B']
['B']
['A, C']
['B, C']]
```

DF2 :

```
Col_Name_X, Col_Name_Y
[['A', 'Paris'] 
['B', 'London']
['C', 'Mexico']]
```

In DF1, I need to replace all values A, B, C, using DF2 which is corresponding table.
Critical point is that in some rows, there are multiple values to replace : ['A, B'] for instance in first row.

I tried 3 ways :
1- split Col_Name_1 to have each value in a separate column and loop with a merge fonction
2- create a dictionnary from DF2 and use replace function on DF1
3- create a dictionnary from DF2 and use map function on DF2

Issue I have is that my DataFrames have 1 000 000 rows.
1 & 2 are consumming too much memory, CPU and time. I cannot get a result.
3 is fast but does not match multiple values from DF1 : A, B return NaN

I assume that it must exist a simple way to do this... Any idea please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mapping by dictionary with splitted values in column in `df1` with `dict.get`, if no match return same value:

```
d = df2.set_index('Col_Name_X')['Col_Name_Y'].to_dict()

f = lambda x: ', '.join(d.get(y,y) for y in x.split(', '))
df1['Col_Name_1'] = df1['Col_Name_1'].apply(f)

print (df1)
       Col_Name_1
0   Paris, London
1          London
2   Paris, Mexico
3  London, Mexico
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks :)